# compilation error with nvcc and BOOST library

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, nvcc

nvcc throws

```
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:29: error: ‘&’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/include/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp:29: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

the has_constraints.hpp already has some suspicious code in it:

```
#if BOOST_WORKAROUND(__SUNPRO_CC, <= 0x580)
  // Work around the following bogus error in Sun Studio 11, by
  // turning off the has_constraints function entirely:
  //    Error: complex expression not allowed in dependent template
  //    argument expression
  inline no has_constraints_(...);
#else
  template <class Model>
  inline yes has_constraints_(Model*, wrap_constraints<Model,&Model::constraints>* = 0);
  inline no has_constraints_(...);
#endif
```

Question: Is this a nvcc - boost incompatibility, or could there be something wrong with my code?

Comment: Actually, this might be more what you are looking for: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=150025

Comment: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2010 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Nov__3_16:16:57_PDT_2010
Cuda compilation tools, release 3.2, V0.2.1221

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

Comment: I keep coming across the same advice: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=215470 "There is a known compatibility issue with boost and nvcc. A work around is to split the sources such that you compile the cuda code with nvcc and the boost code with the host compiler." If there are newer versions out (there is for gcc) and you have a chance to test on them, I'd try that. Otherwise, maybe stick to the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did at the end was to turn has_constraints_ off as in the example quoted in the question for Sun Studio 11

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the "&" before "Model::constraints"? I would think that's the problem. (// it's not apparently)

EDIT:

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=182890 talk about this issue and have some hack work arounds

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=150025

EDIT2:

Well, after running around this for a while, this is what I'm sticking with:

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=215470 "There is a known compatibility issue with boost and nvcc. A work around is to split the sources such that you compile the cuda code with nvcc and the boost code with the host compiler." by Justin Luitjens in the Group: NVIDIA Employees

Try it out, but if you can't make it work, compile separately, and then link them.

Comment: @Michael Hmm, I'll look that up.

Comment: @Michael .. ok, I see it. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp Are there any compiler options that are needed for it?

Comment: there are lots of compiler options. Are you looking for anything specific?

Comment: Hmm, I will have a look at the links

Answer (score 1):

I have a patch here http://code.google.com/p/asadchev/source/browse/trunk/projects/boost/boost-1.46.0.nvcc.patch

Perhaps you can see what is changed and fix your code likewise

Be aware that the source is seen by both, gcc-like and egg-like compiler parts.